# Definition of Coadjoint representation for Lie algebras

Tags: differential-geometry

I have trouble understanding the definition of the coadjoint representation of a Lie algebra.

Typically you first define a natural pairing between the Lie algebra and Lie coalgebra:
\begin{equation}
\langle, \rangle : \mathfrak{g}^* \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
I don't really understand how this is defined, the literature does not seem very explicit. How is this natural pairing defined?

Let  $\mathrm{Ad}_X$ denote the adjoint representation. The coadjoint $\mathrm{Ad}^*_X$ representation is then given by
\begin{equation}
\langle Z,   \mathrm{Ad}_X( Y) \rangle =\langle \mathrm{Ad}^*_X Z,    Y \rangle  \; \; \mathrm{with} \; \;  Z \in \mathfrak{g}^*,  \; \; X,Y \in \mathfrak{g} 
\end{equation}
Do I compute this just by evaluation of the basis?

Would it be possible to supply me with a simple example?

Comment: The pairing is defined by evaluation. $\mathfrak g^*$ consists of functionals $\mathfrak g\to \mathbb R$. So $\langle \phi,X\rangle=\phi(X).$ Then the coadjoint representation  is defined by the formula stated. If you don't get a good answer fleshing this out, I will expand on this, but I have to go right now.

Comment: @JimConant So given some basis $L_1, \ldots L_k$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ I will have $<L_i^*,L_j>= \delta_{ij}$ (where $\delta_{ij} $ is Kronecker delta)? I will try to work out an example tonight and post it on mathstack to see if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In a bit late, but isn't there a minus sign missing in the definition of $\mathrm{Ad}_X^{\ast}$ provided in the original post?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Doubly late, but yes you're right.